# Generate GeoTIFF files from raw data

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I have a tool (a gradiometer) and a GNSS device. I can save the output from the tool and, separately, the GNSS device complete with timings.

What I’m trying to do is work out how to convert this data to a GeoTIFF such that it can be imported directly into Google Earth (etc) as a layer.

Having done some reading on this, it looks fairly straightforward; convert image file to TIFF and add positioning data as metadata, but the articles I read only specified the positions of the corners of the grid, at best.

Is it possible to work with greater precision? If I am taking tool readings at 1Hz and GNSS positioning simultaneously, is it possible to plot all of this data?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We use a Focused question/Best answer model,  so it's important to specify what you have tried, and where you are stuck. Your task is possible, in dozens, if not scores of ways, which makes this quite open-ended. You need to choose a tool or programming language and make an attempt before we can help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a multilayer TIFF, with each layer being 1 second of measurements?

Comment: Are you already creating some image file?

Comment: If what you are trying to do is display your gradiometer data in Google Earth, have you looked at creating a KML file by combining GNSS and gradiometer data (so every epoch of GNSS data had some symbol which showed measurement magnitude and direction?  What are you expecting to see when you open your file in Google Earth?